# Azure KeyVault expiration date update

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to update a secret's expiration date without creating a new version of the secret within KeyVault via the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package? I'm able to do so within the Azure portal, but need to be able to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible to update the expiration date for an existing secret without creating a new version.

Here is quick and dirty sample C# code. Look closely at the `SecretAttributes` and `client.UpdateSecretAsync` method being called.

`Expires` is an attribute for the secret that you need to set.

I am making use of [KeyVaultClientExtensions.UpdateSecretAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.updatesecretasync?view=azure-dotnet)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UpdateKeyVaultSecret
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UpdateSecretAttributes("https://rohitvault1.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret1").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("<my-app-clientid>", "<my-app-client-secret>");
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

            if (result == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetSecretFromVault(string secretKeyIdentifier)
        {
            var client = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessTokenAsync),
                new System.Net.Http.HttpClient());

            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretKeyIdentifier).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return secret.Value;
        }

        public static async Task<string> UpdateSecretAttributes(string secretKeyIdentifier)
        {
            var client = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessTokenAsync),
                new System.Net.Http.HttpClient());

            SecretAttributes attributes = new SecretAttributes();
        attributes.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(15);

            var secret = await client.UpdateSecretAsync(secretKeyIdentifier, null, attributes, null).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return secret.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, there are other programmatic options as well. I'm just mentioning these briefly as the question is pretty generic and someone might land here looking for ways other than C# too:

- **REST API**

  [**Update Secret API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/updatesecret/updatesecret#secretattributes)
- **Azure CLI**

  **[az keyvault secret set-attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set-attributes)**

  Example:

  ```
  az keyvault secret set-attributes --vault-name 'rsvault1' --name 'secret123' --expires '2018-12-25T01:23:45Z'
  ```

Comment: Turns out, as I was using the UpdateSecretAsync method already, it was updating, it's just that Azure portal wasn't refreshing the values even though I was clicking the provided refresh button - eventually a page reload showed that the value had been updated

Comment: @CraigM that makes sense. I've seen that happen on portal side as well.